# Help ID this set!

Tags: set-identification

My school received a bunch of built Lego donations. However this was in with it and we don’t have instructions or know the set!

6 bags has bag three with blue pink and purple mostly with pieces that remind me of a steering wheel for a ship! Has pieces with eye lashes

Every time I upload a photo it says too large

Comment: "Every time I upload a photo it says too large" Have you tried to resize your images? Today's cameras and smartphones take pictures of previously never seen resolution and thus file size - a 50% reduction in the resolution would probably result in a fitting, yet still recognizable image.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the fact that most (if not all) lego "classic" sets group colours by bags, and my guess that "pieces that remind me of a steering wheel for a ship" might mean [round plates with gear teeth](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=35442), I can make an educated guess for [set 11019](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=11019-1).

Note that the instructions booklet for the set show that a blue-pink-purple assembly with gear plates and lashy eyes can be made from bag 3:

[image: excerpt from instructions]